# How to bind multiple events in same hooks in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, events, hook, handsontable

#### Description

How can I bind multiple events into the same hook?

Suppose I have a function named `updateDataDump`, now every time when any of these events occur `afterChange`, `afterColumnMove`, `afterRemoveRow` or `afterRemoveCol`. I want that function to be executed.

```
Handsontable.hooks.add('afterChange', () => {
    updateDataDump();
});

Handsontable.hooks.add('afterColumnMove', () => {
    updateDataDump();
});

Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRemoveRow', () => {
    updateDataDump();
});

Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRemoveCol', () => {
    updateDataDump();
});
```

Is there any way by which I can combine all functions into one?

#### Your environment

- Handsontable version: Version: 0.32.0
- Browser Name and Version: Google Chrome 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)
- Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in option to add a logic to a few hooks at once.

With the solutions that you can choose from is also calling the `updateSettings`

```
hot.updateSettings({

  afterChange: function(){
      updateDataDump()
  }, 

  afterColumnMove: function(){
      updateDataDump()
  }, 

  afterRemoveRow: function(){
    updateDataDump()
  }, 

  afterRemoveCol: function(){
    updateDataDump()
  }, 
});


function updateDataDump(){

}
```

or just use the hook name as the `addHook` method uses a string representation of a hook.

```
var hooks = ['afterChange', 'afterColumnMove', 'afterRemoveRow', 'afterRemoveCol'];

for(var i = 0; i < hooks.length; i++){
    hot.addHook(hooks[i], updateDataDump);
}

function updateDataDump(){

}
```

Comment: Why do you use updateSettings here ? What are the pros of doing this ? The purpose of this function is to change the settings of your table *after* the initialization. (e.g: if the table is empty, you want to change the context menu and make the action "Delete Row" not available anymore. This is a fundamental change of the table compare to your fresh table when you load your webpage). I don't understand why you don't put everything in the initlialization of your table. It seems to be proper way of doing this, IMO.